# Modify sort header URL of the MVC3 Grid (@grid.GetHtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, grid

I have got some MVC3 Grid.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "CenteredHeader",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
```

On that method I filter data via some **generic** `checkboxes`.

```
[IsAuthenticated]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Movies(int? id, FormCollection formCollection)
{
```

**The problem apearas when I try to sort already filtered data. I mean the column header URL doesn't have any parameters and also I cannot use [HttpPost].**

Any clue how do I can access selected checkboxes or modify column header URL when I click those checkboxes?

This link has the column header url of MVC3 Grid.

```
http://localhost:16349/MyWebsite/Movies/807?sort=TechnologyName&sortdir=DESC
```

Thank you!

P.S. Code

```
<h2>
    <a class="mainmenu" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home/Areas")">Areas\</a><a class="mainmenu"href="@Url.Action("Index", "BoxOffice")">Box
        Office\</a><span class="currentmenu">Cinema @ViewBag.ChainName</span></h2>
@{        

    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                 defaultSort: "MovieName",
                 rowsPerPage: 30);
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fecha de inicio y de finalización</legend>Fecha de inicio
        <input type="text" id="startDate" size="10" class="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="startDate" value="@ViewBag.StartDate" />
        Fecha de finalización
        <input type="text" id="endDate" size="10" class="datepicker" autocomplete="off" name="endDate" value="@ViewBag.EndDate"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="button" />
        @if (ViewBag.TechnologyNames != null)
        {
            <div style="margin: 8px;">
                <b>Tecnologias</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                @if (Session["TechList"] == null)
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option_all" id="checkbox_all" checked="checked" value="-1" /> <label>Todos</label>
                    foreach (var technologyName in ViewBag.TechnologyNames)
                    {
                        if (!technologyName.TechnologyID.ToString().Equals("-1"))
                        {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)" id="checkbox_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)"
                                        value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" />  @technologyName.Name
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var lst = (List<string>)Session["TechList"];

                    if (lst.Contains("-1"))
                    {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option_all" id="checkbox_all" checked="checked" value="-1" /> <label>Todos</label>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option_all" id="checkbox_all" value="-1" /> <label>Todos</label>
                    }

                    foreach (var technologyName in ViewBag.TechnologyNames)
                    {
                        bool isSelected = false;

                        foreach (var t in lst)
                        {
                            string n = technologyName.TechnologyID.ToString();

                            if (n.Equals(t))
                            {
                                isSelected = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isSelected)
                        {
                            if (!technologyName.TechnologyID.ToString().Equals("-1"))
                            {                                                   
                    <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="option_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)" id="checkbox_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)"
                                        value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" />  @technologyName.Name
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (!technologyName.TechnologyID.ToString().Equals("-1"))
                            {                                                     
                    <input type="checkbox" name="option_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)" id="checkbox_@(technologyName.TechnologyID)"
                                        value="@technologyName.TechnologyID" />  @technologyName.Name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
<br />
<div id="grid">
    @if (Model != null)
    {

        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "CenteredHeader",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        columns: grid.Columns(
                           grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Detalles", "Movie", new { id = item.MovieID })),
                           grid.Column("MovieName", "Pelicula"),
                                    grid.Column("TechnologyName", "Tecnologia"),
                                grid.Column("Visitors", "Espect.", style: "CenteredNumbers"),
                                grid.Column("TotalSum2", "Monto", format: (item) => item.TotalSum2.ToString("#,0.00"), style: "CenteredNumbers"),
                                grid.Column("MoviePromedio", "TP", format: (item) => item.MoviePromedio.ToString("#,0.00"), style: "CenteredNumbers"),
                                grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Comparativo por complejo", "Compare", new { id = item.MovieID }))
        )
    )     
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the code in which you are rendering this WebGrid in the view?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thank you!!! I just put html.

Comment: Wow, that seems quite a lot of code in your view. Why don't you use view models? Your view seem to be cluttered with code that is not its responsibility. You seem to be fetching stuff from Session, ViewBag, looping, manually generating checkboxes instead of using Html helpers, ...